# How to submit data to another file as it is

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I created a file`upload.php` where user can upload heading, text,images, and set color , background-color. according to their desire,. but how this data can be submitted as it is . i used jquery and javascript for this. for example

to create heading.(i am not writing full script but if anyone need i can explain in more detail)

```
$("#button1").click(function(){var heading = $("<h3></h3>").attr({contenteditable:"true"});
                      $("div").append(heading);});
```

if user want to create simple text  by click button2

```
$("#button2").click(function(){var paragraph=$("<p></p>").attr({contenteditable:"true"});
                                  $("div").append(paragraph);});
```

And if user want to insert image first he has to upload file (long php script) and then insert  image by

```
$("#button3").click(function(){var image= $("<img>")
.attr({src:"images/<?php echo $_FILES["img"]["name"];?>"});
$("div").append(image);});
```

AND user can play with colors as well for set background-color

```
<input type="color" id="background"> <button type="button" onclick="setbackground()">
<script>
function setbackground(){document.getElementsByTagName("div").style.backgroundColor=document.getElementById("background").value;
```

But the question is when user complete all what he want to write,upload.   now how he can submit it so that it can securely uploaded to the site as it is (i.e carrying all the effects user made).
I try to use `<form>` and php but it is difficult to carry out all the css effects using `<form>` and I am using  `<p></p>` not `<input>`. so it is difficult to use`<form>` I am very confused . It is little bit complex but please help. I am not asking whole script just a hint will give me some direction where to go.

Comment: appending to `$("div")`  will apend to all the divs present in your html

Comment: don't worry about that . this is just a example i have set id to div in real script. .you can assume their is only one div.

Comment: ohk ,, then its okay if there's only one div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a simple solution.

You can save all the edit done by user by just saving the user's html using `.html()`

*For Eg:*

```
var user_html = $("your main div").html();
```

You can use it as a string save it the way you want and you can later reproduce it too

*For Eg:*

```
 $("your main div").html(user_html);
```

***NOTE*** : And please give unique ID's to your div's and use the unique ID's for appending.